# What is the difference between the Microsoft.Azure.Storage and WindowsAzure.Storage Nuget packages?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I've always found this very confusing:

- There is a `WindowsAzure.Storage` NuGet package authored by Microsoft which allows you to work with, for example, blob storage (creating blobs, etc.).
- There are also `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.*` packages which accomplish the same thing, also authored by Microsoft.

If your project happens to have dependencies on both, you can have naming conflicts e.g. (The type 'CloudStorageAccount' exists in both 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common, ... and 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, ...).

Here are links to the two alternatives:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet](https://web.archive.org/web/20191121124602/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/README.md

What is the difference and when would I be motivated to use one over the other?

Comment: I'd like to extend the question to cover Azure.Storage.Blobs

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`WindowsAzure.Storage`(latest is v9.3.2) is the legacy Storage SDK we always use and `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.*`(latest v9.4.0) is its new release, nuget available about one year.

Check the [changelog](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Common/changelog.txt) of Storage .NET SDK. List part of those important differences/changes.

1. `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` splits libraries to three parts, Blob, Queue and File, which means we can install separate package instead of the full edition.
2. `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` doesn't support Table API, it is transferred to [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table).
3. `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` added NetStandard2.0 target support since 9.4.0-preview, which supports synchronous methods wrapped over the asynchronous APIs. `WindowsAzure.Storage` on NetStandard only has asynchronous APIs.
4. `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` v9.4 package moves back to use `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` namespace temporarily to ease the transition for existing libraries.

Just make choices based on our requirement.

Comment: removing Tablestorage access from the newer package (basically blocking TS users from .NET Core) is hopefully gonna be fixed, right now it's still full framework only

Comment: I don't understand the choice from Microsoft to keep the old `WindowsAzure.Storage` namespace in the new `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` library. Now I'm ending up with a namespace conflict because I also reference a 3rd party library that uses the old `WindowsAzure.Storage`. I'm trying to set an `extern alias` in my .NET Core project but it's not working. What a hell, so stupid choice Microsoft

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL Microsoft used the old namespaces in version 9 of `Microsoft.Azure.Storage`, in version 10 (released 2019-04-09: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/10.0.0 ) the namespaces were changed to `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.*`). Just stick to version 10+ and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Dai thanks, updating the library to latest version resolves the conflicts.

Answer (score 40):

There are now three levels:

1. `WindowsAzure.Storage` - up to v9.3.3 - don't use this anymore.
2. `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` - v9.4.0 to v11.1.7 - older
3. `Azure.Storage` - v12.x - use this library.

All the Azure libraries are being consolidated into the `Azure` namespace, so the newer libraries all start with `Azure` (not `Microsoft.Azure` or `WindowsAzure`) and you should use those when available.

Comment: It seems to only be partially correct: for example, `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement` is the up-to-date namespace; there's no non-`Microsoft`.-prefix one

Comment: I believe these are called Tracks 0, 1 and 2 based on what I learned from here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/10842  - but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Is Azure.Storage the same with its deprecated libraries?