# Ambiguous CloudStorageAccount in aspnetcore when used with bot framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-storage

I have just upgraded bot framework project which is based on SDK v4 and built using aspnet core and now I end up getting conflict for CloudStorageAccount class. It says

*The type 'CloudStorageAccount' exists in both 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common, Version=9.4.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'*

Anyone also faced the same issue? Please note that I have already tried to use an alias for the namespace but it still does not work and we have no clue why.

The closest match w.r.t this issue we found was on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214947/what-is-the-difference-between-the-microsoft-azure-storage-and-windowsazure-stor) and sounds similar issue there too. (comment by Jerome) but remains unanswered.

Sharing the version of each nuget I have installed in the project

[image]

Please suggest if anyone has faced it or has any suggestion.

Comment: You're experiencing this as a result of this change: "As of version 9.4.0, this library has been split into multiple parts and replaced" [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/). Please also refer to this GitHub issue: [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage namespace causes massive conflicts (ambiguous references)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/842)

Answer (score 1):

There is a github thread about this issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/1421)

To recap, issue was caused by conflicts in the AspNetCore references. The issue was resolved by going into the .csproj file and removing the references to WindowsAzure.Storage.

```
<PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
```

Additionally, there will be a PR soonish that will address this dependency.