# Referencing services from CloudStorageAccount when migrating from WindowsAzure.Storage to Azure.Storage packages

Tags: c#, azure

I have a code-base that makes extensive use of the **WindowsAzure.Storage** nuget package for access to *Queues, Tables and Blobs*.  The package is now flagged as deprecated with the indication that the functionality has been broken up into individual components under the **Azure.Storage** package-set.

[This StackOverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214947/what-is-the-difference-between-the-microsoft-azure-storage-and-windowsazure-stor/62393869#62393869) provides some description of the replacement packages but it's unclear how much of the restructuring is complete and what combination of legacy and new packages are required to migrate at this time.

I've been unable to find any up-to-date migration guide and example code/documentation for the new packages tends to focus on basic operations.

Specifically, I'm having difficulty accessing the new services from a top-level storage account.

The current code uses a pattern like this...

```
    var accountName = "...";
    var accountKey ="..............";
    var credentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
    var account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials,true);

    //for table access...
    var client = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
    var table = client.GetTableReference(tableName);
    
    //for queue access
    var client = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
    var queue = client.GetQueueReference(queueName);
    
    //for blob access 
    var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = client.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    var blob =   container.GetBlockBlobReference(path);
```

What would be the equivalent using the new  packages and what combination of packages would I need?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need 3 separate Nuget packages:

1. [`Azure.Storage.Blobs`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs): For managing blobs
2. [`Azure.Storage.Queues`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Queues): For managing queues and
3. [`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table): For managing tables.

As far as creating an instance of `CloudStorageAccount` is concerned, it is not available in Azure.Storage.Blobs and Azure.Storage.Queues. You will have to deal with it in a different manner. For Tables, CloudStorageAccount is available in Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table namespace.

For example, the following code in old SDK

```
var container = client.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var blob =   container.GetBlockBlobReference(path);
```

Need to be changed to something like:

```
var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);//Use this client to perform operations on blob container.
var blockBlobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName);//Use this client to perform operations on block blob.
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, that is very useful.  Your answer implies that it is no longer possible to "navigate" from a storage account to the blobs/queues within it.  Do you know if this is a deliberate design decision in the new API or it's just that this functionality hasn't been ported yet?

Comment: ...And one other point to help clarify the answer.  Is the "connection string" expected in the new API the connection string of the Storage Account (from the Portal) or some connection string for the blob/queue portion of the account?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I am not part of Storage SDK team so I would be speculating but I believe it is a deliberate design decision and I think we can't expect the storage account object to surface in the SDK. FWIW, I personally think that the new design is awful. It is quite convoluted and complex (wait till you get into Shared Access Signatures :)).

Comment: `Is the "connection string" expected in the new API the connection string of the Storage Account (from the Portal) or some connection string for the blob/queue portion of the account?` - Yes. You can use full connecting string. Each SDK will pick up relevant endpoint related to their service if defined in the connecting string.

Comment: Great  - thanks! Yes, we use SAS's so sounds like lots of fun ahead... ;-)