# Azure Blob client library for .Net 4.5.1 Website fails to install

Tags: vb.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an ASP.Net website on Azure based on .Net 4.5.1.

I am trying to do some dev work on my laptop with Azure blobs.

For this I have Azure Storage Emulator 5.10 on my laptop. Now I need to install a client library in my Visual Studio 2019 website project to be able to write blob uploading code, so I tried installing `Azure.Storage.Blobs.12.4.4` from NuGet console but it gave me following errors ( as in screenshot below).

**Question**:

What Nuget package can I use for my situation? I tried the oldest available version for Azure.Storage.Blobs which is 12.0.0 as of today, but even that gave the same error message. I did succeed in installing `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.11.1.7`, but not sure if this is the correct package for asp.net website targeting .Net 4.5.1 and whether I need to install additional packages.

[image: NuGet install error for Azure.Storage.Blobs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [Azure.Storage.Blobs.12.4.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs), it dependency is **.NETStandard 2.0**. So as your website is on .net 4.5.1, it will get error message.

As your website is on .net 4.5.1, when install `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.11.1.7`, it will not work. Because it only support .NETFramework 4.5.2.

[image]

You can upgrade your framework to 4.5.2 or if you still want to use .NETFramework 4.5.1, you could use [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/).

**Note: `WindowsAzure.Storage` package has been deprecated.**

And you can refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214947/what-is-the-difference-between-the-microsoft-azure-storage-and-windowsazure-stor) to understand the difference between the `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` and `WindowsAzure.Storage` Nuget packages

Comment: I had to update my website project to 4.6.1 since Net 2 standard was first implemented by .Net 4.6.1 framework according to this matrix: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support.

Comment: Also, I was able  to successfully install `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.11.1.7` on .Net 4.5.1 Framework. But you said it will not work?

Comment: Yes, I can also install Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.11.1.7 on .Net 4.5.1, but when code could not load the library.

Answer (score 0):

For any how look to maintain an old app like my self. you can move your app to framework 4.8 and still use Microsoft.Azure.Storage lib.
it works for me