# Azure.Storage.Blobs vs Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob dll for Azure Blob management

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I am going to develop a Web API in .NET Core to use Azure blob. It will contain methods to create container, Block Blob and Append Blob. Also, it needs to update and read Block Blob and Append Blob. Blob size will vary from 1 MiB to 300 MiB. 
I have following questions in my mind:

1. Which library I should use Azure.Storage.Blobs or Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob?
2. In case of Azure.Storage.Blobs package, how to create a blob if its not exists (I couldn't find sample code for blob creation)?
3. In case of Azure.Storage.Blobs package, what will be the performance whether its been improved when compared to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob or the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214947/what-is-the-difference-between-the-microsoft-azure-storage-and-windowsazure-stor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the Microsoft.Azure.Storage and WindowsAzure.Storage Nuget packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214947/what-is-the-difference-between-the-microsoft-azure-storage-and-windowsazure-stor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The WindowsAzure library is old, and is replaced by the Azure library. I wouldn't use it for new development; it exists to keep legacy programs working but is no longer actively developed
2. You upload it. Seems to be some confusion in your mind about what a blob is? If a file on disk doesn't exist, you write one and then it exists. Did you mean to ask about creating a container?
3. There probably is some performance or feature improvement, but I don't know of one out of my head; take a look at the release notes for Azure since v9.3.3ish (it was around that time the package was switched) to see what features are added. The fact that WindowsAzure is the legacy library would be enough for me to not use it for new development, but we use both libs in various different projects and don't have any "wow, that's slow" or "wow, that's fast" thoughts on either of them- they both work